# Python Class - Komodo showing red text in debug but no error produced

Tags: python, debugging

I am pretty new to python and object oriented programming.

I am creating a class in Python, were you have the name of the mix and the ingredients like a matrix. Each line has "Malt Name", "Malt Quantity", "Time to add Malt"

Below you can see the code

```py
class MaltMix:
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):
        self._mixName = kwargs['name'] if 'name' in kwargs else "Malt Mix Name"
        self._maltMatrix = []   
        
    def show(self):
        print("Name of the Mix: {}".format(self._mixName))
        print("Number of Different Malts: {}".format(len(self._maltMatrix)))
        print("Mix Info: {}".format(self._maltMatrix))
    
    def add(self, mName, mQuantity, mTime):
        self._maltMatrix.append([mName, mQuantity, mTime])   

def main():
    mix1 = MaltMix(name = "First Malt Mix Name")
    mix1.show()
    mix1.add("Malt1", "10", "00:45:00")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output seems correct, although the last line is red. Any reason why?

Output:

```
Name of the Mix: First Mix
Quantity of Different Malts: 0
Mix Info: []
Name of the Mix: First Mix
Quantity of Different Malts: 1
Mix Info: [['Malt1', '10', '00:45:00']]
Name of the Mix: First Mix
Quantity of Different Malts: 2
Mix Info: [['Malt1', '10', '00:45:00'], ['Malt2', '20', '03:45:00']]
Name of the Mix: First Mix
Quantity of Different Malts: 2
**Mix Info: [['Malt1', '10', '00:45:00'], ['Malt2', '20', '03:45:00']]**
```

Comment: Depending on the Editor / Linter you use, the line might be marked because the `main()` function is called on the same line as the `if`. While this is not a syntax error, the linter tells you that this is not good practice by marking the line. Normally there is a hint / popup which tells you why the code is markde.

Comment: As an aside: `self._mixName = kwargs.get('name', 'Malt Mix Name')`

Comment: I just want to say thank you for your support!